# Basic gradle question

Tags: gradle

I have installed gradle and i am at least trying to get the most basic of build running but nothing. I have tried to run the sample project that comes with gradle. From this directory

$GRADLE_HOME/samples/userguide/multiproject/firstExample

i run this command

```
gradle hello
```

and this is output

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.gradle.Main).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.


gradle -v
```

gives me this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 0.8
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle buildtime: Monday, September 28, 2009 2:01:59 PM CEST
Groovy: 1.6.4
Ant: Apache Ant version 1.7.0 compiled on December 13 2006
Ivy: 2.1.0-rc2
Java: 1.6.0_20
JVM: 16.3-b01-279
JVM Vendor: Apple Inc.
OS Name: Mac OS X
```

Any ideas ???

Comment: If you question has been answered, please grant the answer flag.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the JAVA_HOME and GRADLE_HOME variables are defined correctly and that your unzipped distro is not corrupted or missing any files.

I would upgrade to the latest version, 0.9-rc-3, even though it is not a "stable" release.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem could be that the unarchiving tool you used does not restore **file permissions**. This hint is mentioned in the documentation of *gradle*.

> For Un*x users
>
> You need a GNU compatible tool to unzip Gradle, if you want the file
>   permissions to be properly set. We mention this as some zip front ends
>   for Mac OS X don't restore the file permissions properly.

Source: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#installation